# How to change default margin for white-space: nowrap?

Tags: html, css

This is 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FPBWr/518/)
I want make img tag:
`margin-right:1px;`
but when I set 
`white-space: nowrap;`
i can't do that.
How can i do??

Comment: Please include code. Just jsfiddle is not enough.

Comment: I don't see any margins. Are you talking about the whitespace?

Comment: @nicael Check jsf link. I had an update for that.

Comment: change to white-space: normal;

Comment: white-space: normal; can't work, too.

Comment: I changed 1 to 100 to see the problem but it's working http://jsfiddle.net/FPBWr/521/ it's having the right margin on image. what's the problem?

Comment: you want to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/FPBWr/522/ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/FPBWr/522/

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#myWorkContent{
    width: 100%;
        height: 65px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-top: 30px;
}
#myWorkContent img {
    display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    margin-right:-3px;
}
```